# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on null after migration from magento1 to magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

After Migration when I open the order detail page from the Grid admin side I face one error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on null in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/vendor/magento2/module-sales/Model/Order.php:737
Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/View.php(92): Magento\Sales\Model\Order->canEdit()
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(208): Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View->_construct()
#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->__construct(Object(Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context), Array)
#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Template.php(67): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->__construct(Object(Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context), Array)
#4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Widget/Container.php(56): Magento\Backend\Block\Template->__construct(Object(Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context), Array) #5 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order.php on line 737
```

[image]

Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: which tool did you use for migration?

Comment: Ubertheme Migration Tools

Comment: Did you download from  Github or purchase module ?

Comment: Download from GIT